# Interpretation of a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics

Let us say that I have the partial differential equation,

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial W}{\partial t}=(b-a)\partial_p\partial_qW -(\dot{a}\partial_p^2+\dot{b}\partial_q^2)W\,,
\end{align}

where $a=a(t)$, $b=b(t)$, and $W=W(q,p,t)$. As this looks similar to the diffusion equation, my guess is that the last term represents the diffusion with respect to $p$ and $q$. Is there a physical meaning for the $(b-a)\partial_p\partial_qW$ term? Alternatively, is this differential equation known by a specific name?

Comment: What is $W$? Is it a function of $t$, $p$ and $q$?

Comment: Yes - I've edited the question to include it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the $\partial_p\partial_qW$ term can be interpreted in isolation. The entire PDE is an anisotropic diffusion equation
$$\frac{\partial W}{\partial t} = \nabla\cdot(\mathbf D\,\nabla W)$$
where $\mathbf D$ is the diffusion coefficient matrix, in this case
$$\mathbf D=\begin{bmatrix}-\dot b & \frac12(b-a) \\ \frac12(b-a) & -\dot a\end{bmatrix}.$$
I believe the matrix $\mathbf D$ needs to be positive definite for the equation to be well-posed.

Answer (score 0):

If we look carefully and replace

$p \implies X$

$q \implies Y$.

So that we can relate X- and Y- with space co-ordinates.

Then,

$W = f(X, Y, t)$

This makes the things easy and the given equation is comparable to **damped wave equation**.

Comment: I don't see how it is comparable. Can you explicitly compare them and point out the similarities?